# What is the fastest/efficient way to process thousands of text files in Matlab?

Tags: database, matlab, performance, file

I am working on a Matlab application that loads numerical data from thousands of structured text files and then perform some light statistical analysis. My application takes a bit of time to run. I am searching for ways to make it faster.

I suspect that multiple memory access on a hard drive, to read the files, is what taking the most time.

Do you think that storing the data from text files into an SQL database would make my application run any faster?

PS: Sometimes I need to run the application on the same dataset multiple times.

To work around this issue so far I process the text files seperately, extract only information I need, organize them in a matrix and store it in a .mat file that will be used as input to my main application. The extraction part still takes time but I noticed some time gain on the main application.

The problem with this approach: if different information is needed from the text files, the .mat files would become absolete and therefore need to generate new ones.

Comment: Why can't you exactly replicate the information in the text files in .mat files, which will likely be much quicker to access, then just do any processing on these to produce new information? Jumping to database creation sounds like overkill, but it's completely subjective depending on what you're doing, what's in the text files, how often you're accessing the data, how big the files are, what data is in the files, whether you can use tall tables, whether you can process in parallel (locally or on a cluster)... this question is too broad and opinion based as-is

Comment: I only access text files once to generate the .mat files
These text files are logs from a signal receiver (1 file per ms) and each line of the file contains a variable name/description and value. For now i'm only extracting 11 variables but the requirements could change in the future and would need to extract more.

Comment: My previous comment still stands, 1 file per ms seems insanely inefficient, but without an [edit] to your question to make it a lot more specific, we can't help you - there isn't a silver bullet here, you'll just have to start testing ideas!

Comment: I agree with Wolfie here, it looks like you should just spend the time _once_ to import and convert all your text files into `.mat` files. Access to them is always going to be faster than parsing text data. While you're doing it, think if there is a benefit of may be grouping some of the text file data into the same `.mat` file (depending of the size of each item).

Comment: I don't know that a .mat file is going to work if the current system is generated a new file every ms. I'm amazed the OS is keeping up. @SaraB you say the data is structured and you're grabbing 11 variables. Are they always the same structure? Can you just write a binary file that concatonates each ms to an existing file? You could start a new file every 1s. That will reduce the write/read overhead (substantially since you're not using as many fopen/fclose and saving OS calls). And you can jump around in the binaries as needed.